# How is "Modified DPS" caculated?

Tags: torchlight-2

- My weapon DPS is 169.
- Modified DPS is 320.
- Total damage is 221-357. The Average of this is 289.
- Attack speed is 0,91 seconds per attack.

How is the modified DPS caculated? The closest i get is 289 / 0,91 = 317,58

Comment: Do you have any percentage bonuses to your attack given by any of your gear?

Comment: where is this modified DPS written?

Comment: and to make a guess about your question: Did you take critical strikes into account? to do so, you have to compute `(average damage * (1 + critical damage * critical chance))/attack speed`

Answer (score 1):

This is a "Mathematical Machine" for calculating modified D.P.S. towards the bottom of the link he tells you vaguely how it works but here is the link to this guys page.                                     http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=53838