# How to find your character's total DPS in torchlight 2?

Tags: torchlight-2

Many abilities deal damage based on your current DPS, but the problem is I don't know how much my DPS is. In the character's menu your current damage is shown, but to compute DPS I need more data like total attack rate (which I also couldn't find). Do I have to just guess my total DPS or is it written somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean DPS?

Comment: I've also always wondered about "conveys X damage over Y time" effects - as far as I can tell that effect is not reflected in any DPS number anywhere.

Comment: @jw013 convey damage seem to completely have a different mechanic thus it's not reflected in any DPS number anywhere. eg. it won't add buff more than once, so if the effect is to convey 30 damage over 5 seconds, it's basically adding your DPS by 5.

Comment: @Gajoo Thanks - whether or not that effect stacked was another thing I wondered as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you press <kbd>J</kbd> to bring up the **Arcane Statistics** panel, you can see all kinds of useful, and detailed information about your character.

It contains information on things like your resistances, your hit chance, your calculated damage per hit (not sure about actual 'DPS'), attack speed, your regeneration speeds, various percentages, and lots more that I can't remember right now.  If your DPS is listed anywhere in the game, this is where it will be.  If it isn't, the information you need to calculate it definitely is.

---

*Extra Info About Attack Speed*

If you're just looking for base attack speed, that's usually listed in seconds when you hover over your weapon.

> NOTE: If you're wielding two weapons with different speeds, you will attack with each at its own speed (your left and right handed attacks will be different speeds).

Comment: It doesn't contain my total DPS. For damage related numbers it just shows all other variables I could see by hovering over weapons, so basically it's not contain any extra information. It's just everything in one place.

Comment: @Gajoo Are you sure?  [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98903/how-to-find-your-characters-total-dps-in-torchlight-2/98906#comment134934_98906) seems to suggest that there's a listing called 'Modified DPS', is that not there for you?

Comment: Even if there is such a thing I can't find it. by the way, why did you link to my own question?

Comment: Hah, I didn't even realize it was you!  Where did you see 'Modified DPS' then?

Comment: @Gajoo Anyway, if your DPS isn't listed here, it's not listed anywhere, which stinks.

Comment: I guess you meant [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95488/how-is-modified-dps-caculated). but he didn't say where he had found that Modifed DPS either.

Comment: Under arcane stats don't forget there are `+` signs for submenus that you can expand, including one each for your "left hand" and "right hand" (both are under attack / offensive stats).  The DPS listed there is the closest I can think of to true DPS.

Comment: @Gajoo Whoops, that's the question I meant to link.  Sorry!