# My Shield has two separate stats of block chance. Do they stack?

Tags: torchlight-2

So I'm currently equipped with a shield called "Roundhaven". And in the stats it states two block chances(no "+%block chance" just "%block chance"). There is a "14% block chance" and several lines down another "15% block chance", see the below picture. Does this mean the shield gives me 29% block chance? Or is it a bug?

[image: Roundhaven shield]

Comment: I seem to remember you could look at your character's stats and see the total values for everything. Does that help or am I misremembering?

Comment: yeah i forgot to look at the arcane statistics menu. Indeed it stacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found at least three different locations where they talk about 29% block change, so I think it stacks, and it is not a bug or anything. I have no idea why it is separated into two lines.

Sources:

- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Torchlight/comments/13qxpt/first_time_playing_tl2_made_a_summoner_engineer/c76fqwp):

  > I found one this week, and also Roundhaven, a 29% block lvl19 shield...
- [Runicgames forum](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=43380&start=20)

  > Manticore and Grell (and probably others) have a chance to drop roundhaven. It's 29% block
- [UrGameTips](http://www.urgametips.com/2012/11/torchlight-ii-embermage-frost-mage.html)

  > The Lvl 23 "Roundhaven" Shield has 29% chance to Block

Comment: It is separated because one is the base block chance of the shield and the other is the property that was randomly selected which happens to further increase block chance.  With legendaries, they follow this pattern but are typically fixed properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Arcane Statistics screen (default key: <kbd>J</kbd>) to bring up a view that accurately shows the *total* values of each of your stats, including buffs, equipment, skills, etc.

Lots of info available online, including right here on Arqade:

- [Torchlight 2 - How powerful is a weapon, exactly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86333/8090)
- [How to find your character's total DPS in torchlight 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/98906/8090)